# displacing of error bar use ggbarplot from ggpubr package, when there are NA

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr, errorbar

The codes work when there are observations for all group in the dataset. However, when a group of data is NA, the error bars will be displaced. Here is an example:

```
library(ggpubr)
# Load the ToothGrowth dataset
data(ToothGrowth)
ggbarplot(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len", 
   add = "mean_se", 
   color = "supp", palette = "jco",
   position = position_dodge(0.8)
) + 
  ggtitle("no NA in dataset")
```

[image]

```
# Motified dataset
ToothGrowth$len[ToothGrowth$dose == 2 & ToothGrowth$supp == "VC"] <- NA

head(ToothGrowth)
ggbarplot(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len", 
   add = "mean_se", 
   color = "supp", palette = "jco",
   position = position_dodge(0.8)
)+
  ggtitle("one group is NA")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fix your issue by setting `preserve = "single"` in `position_dodge()`:

```r
library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

ToothGrowth$len[ToothGrowth$dose == 2 & ToothGrowth$supp == "VC"] <- NA

ggbarplot(ToothGrowth,
  x = "dose", y = "len",
  add = "mean_se",
  color = "supp", palette = "jco",
  position = position_dodge(0.8, preserve = "single")
) +
  ggtitle("one group is NA")
```

[image]